# What's the meaning & structure of "Another stripped faculty doors of banners referencing Taiwan"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

What's the meaning & structure of "Another stripped faculty doors of banners referencing Taiwan"?

When reading an article "Get China's pernicious Confucius Institutes out of US colleges"(http://thehill.com/opinion/education/375092-get-chinas-pernicious-confucius-institutes-out-of-us-colleges), I met the sentence and was confused, even though I recognized every word.

Answer (score 2):

It means another [person] stripped banners from the doors while 'someone else' did 'something else.' I am guessing there was more information before this sentence.

Comment: Yes, there are more information, which I have already shown. Your answer is helpful, then I looked up to Collins and learnt "strip sb of sth". Thanks.